# How to check touch event if touch is sprite or body in AndEngine?

Tags: android, andengine

I'm pretty new to AndEngine, and I have a question. I want to make it so if I touch on the sprite or the body then something will remove that sprite or body for me.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
final Sprite mySprite = newSprite(100, 220, this.mySpriteTextureRegion) {
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

                          // here you can use the code
                        }
    };
```

have to register with screen for touch area as

```
    scene.registerTouchArea(mySprite);
    scene.setTouchAreaBindingEnabled(true);
```

May be it helpful to you..

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

Implement your class with `IOnSceneTouchListener`

```
scene.setOnSceneTouchListener(this);
```

And you can write your stuff in the below implemented method.

```
@Override
    public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent event) {

        // your stuff here
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final Sprite face = new Sprite(centerX, centerY, this.mFaceTextureRegion) {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                            yourSceneClass.this.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                 /* Now it is save to remove the entity! */
                            pScene.detachChild(yourSceneClass.this.face);
                            }
                    });
                    }
            };

pScene.attachChild(face);
pScene.registerTouchArea(face);
pScene.setTouchAreaBindingEnabled(true);
```

It should be something in this general direction.

http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/#hg%2Fsrc%2Forg%2Fanddev%2Fandengine%2Fexamples

Has a lot of examples of the person who made andengine, it's a good idea to atleast look at all of them once.